# laravel windows local phpunit.bat became empty

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have been working away on dusk broswer tests, and went back to some of my phpUnit unit tests, and ran:

```
cd {laravelHomeFolder}
{laravelHomeFolder}> vendor\bin\phpunit.bat
```

and to my suprise, nothing happened!

I found that the phpunit.bat file was truncated - 0 bytes long.

What should the content of this file be??

Laravel 5.4.36

Answer (score 0):

I had a backup of my laravel folder from a few days ago so I found the content of phpunit.bat should be:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
php "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```

I am not sure what made it disappear, but in case anyone else has the same issue, here is the file content.